# PreparedStatement Update showing error ORA-00927 missing equal sign

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to update the records in database according to data read from an Excel sheet. I have more than 50 columns in db whose column names are stored in an array columnNames[].
I use following code to create the Sql query.

```
 String sqlUpdate= "Update "+tableName+
             " set "+columnNames[0]+"=?";
     for (int i=1;i<columnCount;i++)
     {
         sqlUpdate= sqlUpdate+","+columnNames[i]+"=?";
     }
     sqlUpdate= sqlUpdate+
             " where demand_id=?";
```

the equivalent query obtained to printing it on console is :

```
Update fulfillment_plan set DEMAND_ID=?,SBU=?,PROJ_DOMAIN=?,JOBCODE=?,INDENT_STATUS=?,JC_CREATED_ON=?,PROJECT_NAME=?,CUSTOMER_NAME=?,GROUP_CUSTOMER=?,US_DEMANDS=?,SUITE_NAME=?,ROLE_NAME=?,LOCATION=?,COUNTRY=?,GEO=?,AREA=?,OPEN_POS=?,PRODUCT=?,DEMAND_TYPE=?,POSITIONS_TO_FULFILL_Q4=?,FULFILLMENT_PLAN_Q4=?,TA_STATUS_Q4=?,POSITIONS_TO_FULFILL_Q3=?,FULFILLMENT_PLAN_Q3=?,TA_STATUS_Q3=?,POSITIONS_TO_FULFILL_Q2=?,FULFILLMENT_PLAN_Q2=?,TA_STATUS_Q2=?,POSITIONS_TO_FULFILL_Q1=?,FULFILLMENT_PLAN_Q1=?,TA_STATUS_Q1=?,NET_ADD_TYPE=?,ESSENTIAL_SKILL=?,SUITE_SKILLS=?,ADDITIONAL_SKILLS=?,POSITIONS_WITH_PROPOSALS=?,POSITIONS_WITHOUT_PROPOSALS=?,DEM_ST_DATE=?,OVER_DUE_STATUS=?,OVERDUE_DAYS=?,LEAD_TIME_DAYS=?,LEAD TIME BUCKET=?,DEM_END_DATE=?,CREATED_ON=?,INDENT_CREATED_ON=?,EBD=?,OPPORTUNITYID=?,LOAD_DATE=?,PROJECT_NUMBER=?,CUSTOMER_NO=?,CUSTOMER_SUB_GEO=?,DEMAND_STATUS=?,ENGAGEMENT_TYPE=?,INVOICE_TYPE=?,INDENT_CLASSIFICATIONS=?,PROJ_STAT=?,EFD_SLA=?,RM_EMP_NAME=?,MONTH=?,QUARTER=?,YEAR=?,ACCOUNT_ID=?,ACCOUNT_TEXT=?,STATUS=? where demand_id=?
```

Then i have set the values to the '?' and on executing the above prepared statement in am getting the "missing equal sign" error. I have been looking into it for around 3 hours now and am not able to solve it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the `LEAD TIME BUCKET` column name, which should either have underscores (like the other column names) or be escaped somehow - the spaces within the column name are causing the error. It would be better to have underscores in order to be consistent with your other columns, and to make the SQL simpler.

(I'd also suggest adding spaces within your SQL - e.g. one after every comma - so that the SQL can be reformatted in a text editor by line-breaking on spaces, making it easier to read. I'd have more whitespace in the Java code too, but that's clearly a matter of personal/team preference.)

Comment: @Zubair, You should consider accepting this answer since this worked for you.